# Should I use C# App.config for my custom application settings?

Tags: c#, config

I need to store a few settings (connection strings, folder paths) in a config file.

Should I use App.config?

Seems obvious, but....

1) App. contains some .NET config stuff (packages, versiosn etc) which I don't ever want anyone to be able to touch - I'd rather always these get compiled into the program.

2) It feels weird to have my dev-mode config settings compiled into the program, and invoked when App.Config is missing (defaults to built in resource or something)

3) I like clean config files so I can tell at a glance what the settings are (and I have OCD) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, stuff it all into `app.config`. My reasoning is, nothing in `app.config` is *really* editable by the end user, even those bits that only the end user would know (connection strings and folder paths). Do you want a non computer-literate person editing an XML file with Notepad? I know I don't.

The only reliable way to get end-user values into `app.config` is to prompt the user for them during installation, and write them yourself as a custom action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's best practice, and prevents people from having to recompile your application to make basic config changes: ex. a new user needs to get an automatic email, much easier to alter a config file than recompile and re-deploy the app.  In regards to your config file problem, here's an elegant solution: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx

I prefer to just rename the files, or keep commented strings around depending on how much I have to do to move from dev to production.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd never suggest hard coding these values into the program - the choice is between App.Config and (say) my own custom Settings.xml

Comment: app.config is an xml file dude.  Your solution would just re-invent the wheel, and no the app.config is not exposed to the end user, the only possible way I could think of accessing it would be through the file system, or some sort of buffer overflow.  Even so, there are situations where you can't trust your fellow devs, esp. at larger orgs, so there's config obfuscation using a tool provided by MS I believe: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx  . I've also been known to stored encrypted values in a db.

Comment: App.config is actually exposed to the user, in the form <yourapp>.exe.config - that's the whole point of it, so the settings can be edited.

Answer (score 0):

My rule for *.config files is to use them when I want the ability to change a setting without re-deploying binaries. If I don't care about requiring a deployment to make a change, then I'll use constants. If I'm in doubt, I'll use the config file. I almost **always** use config files.

When I **do** use the *.config for something, I'll expose those values through another "Configuration" class that has one static read-only property for each value I wish to expose. i.e. if my app config has a setting

```
<add key="ServerLoadTime" value="-30" />
```

Then my configuration class might look like:

```
public static class Configuration
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the number of minutes before prior to the event that the server is started.
    /// </summary>
    public static int ServerLoadTime
    {
        get
        {
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerLoadTime"] != null)
                return int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerLoadTime"]);

            Logging.Write("ServerLoadTime is missing from the Configuration file.", EventLogEntryType.Warning, Logging.Sources.General, "Configuration.ServerLoadTime", null);
            return -30; // return a default value.
        }
    }
```

}

This approach creates a standardized encapsulation that provides:

- A quick way to reference the values without having to go though CM and checking validity.
- A surface to deal with badly configured values/missing values.
- A place to cast the strings that come from a config file into the type needed.
- A place to log missing values while still providing a default-of-last-resort.
- A place to deal to attach logic to a result if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd never suggest hard coding these values into the program - the choice is between App.Config and (say) my own custom Settings.xml –Brendan

Comment: You didn't mention XML files as an option. Either way, I don't have a problem with hard-coded constants in an application if I know they will rarely if ever change (i.e. const double Pi = 3.141592653;) (and I know you can use Math.Pi; this is an example).